# UWP-App created files not indexed in Windows 10 1803

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, full-text-indexing

In my UWP App I am creating files that should be indexed by the Windows-index so they can be found later using full-text search.

```
public async Task TestFullTextSearch()
{
   StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder;
   CreateFile(folder.Path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "myDocument.txt", "Some text 123");
   await Task.Delay(5000); // to ensure that the file is already index before querying
   int numberOfResults = await SearchForResults(folder, "*");
   // numberOfResults is 1 in Windows 10, 1709 and 0 in 1803
}

public void CreateFile(string path, string text)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(text);
    }
}

private async Task<int> SearchForResults(StorageFolder folder, string searchString)
{
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, new List<string>() { "*" });
    queryOptions.UserSearchFilter = searchString;
    StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
    return files.Count;
}
```

In the example above, when executing the code under Windows 10, 1709, `numberOfResults` is 1. When executing the same code under Windows 10, 1803, `numberOfResults` is 0.

In both cases, the location is added to the Windows-index (added via "Indexing Options").

I checked the permissions and they appear to be exactly the same. I also tried to create a file manually in the respective folder and use the windows search of the Windows Explorer, it shows 0 results (under 1803, under 1709 the results are shown as expected). In a few cases, the created file ended up in the query and was searchable, I have no clue why.

I tried this under 3 different Windows 10, 1803 machines and the results are exactly the same (and on several 1709 machines, here it works fine).

Comment: Have you tried reporting the issue on the Insider Hub?

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid Thanks for the suggestion. The Feedback hub doesn't let me sign in, so I created the feedback anonymously.

Comment: Great, if you need me to help with that let me know and I'll add an upvote for the feedback if give description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself:
Within the "LocalCache" and "LocalState" (and maybe also other app folders), a folder named "Indexed" is automatically added to the Windows search index. The folder has to be created directly below the "LocalCache" or "LocalState" folder.

So by creating a folder named "Indexed" and putting files/folders into that folder, the files become indexed.

See the working code below (works now in Windows 10, 1709 and 1803). I only changed the first line to create the "Indexed" folder.

```
public async Task TestFullTextSearch()
{
    StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Indexed", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    CreateFile(folder.Path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "myDocument.txt", "Some text 123");
    await Task.Delay(5000); // to ensure that the file is already index before querying
    int numberOfResults = await SearchForResults(folder, "*");
    // numberOfResults is 1 in Windows 10, 1709 and 1 in 1803
}

public void CreateFile(string path, string text)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(text);
    }
}

private async Task<int> SearchForResults(StorageFolder folder, string searchString)
{
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, new List<string>() { "*" });
    queryOptions.UserSearchFilter = searchString;
    StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
    return files.Count;
}
```

To check whether the "Indexed" folder really is indexed, go to Indexing Options. The "Indexed" folder is always checked and the checkmark cannot be removed.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder